# Why "subs_.push_back" in listener_with_userdata.cpp

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the tutorial of listener, there is an example for `listener_with_userdata`, why we use `push_back` to initialise the three different callback functions.

```
class Listener
{
public:
  ros::NodeHandle node_handle_;
  ros::V_Subscriber subs_;

  Listener(const ros::NodeHandle& node_handle)
  : node_handle_(node_handle)
  {
  }

  void init()
  {
    subs_.push_back(node_handle_.subscribe<std_msgs::String>("chatter", 1000, boost::bind(&Listener::chatterCallback, this, _1, "User 1")));
    subs_.push_back(node_handle_.subscribe<std_msgs::String>("chatter", 1000, boost::bind(&Listener::chatterCallback, this, _1, "User 2")));
    subs_.push_back(node_handle_.subscribe<std_msgs::String>("chatter", 1000, boost::bind(&Listener::chatterCallback, this, _1, "User 3")));
  }

  void chatterCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg, std::string user_string)
  {
    ROS_INFO("I heard: [%s] with user string [%s]", msg->data.c_str(), user_string.c_str());
  }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "listener_with_userdata");
  ros::NodeHandle n;

  Listener l(n);
  l.init();

  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

For the `init()` part.

```
void init()
 {
        subs_.push_back(node_handle_.subscribe<std_msgs::String>("chatter", 1000, boost::bind(&Listener::chatterCallback, this, _1, "User 1")));
        subs_.push_back(node_handle_.subscribe<std_msgs::String>("chatter", 1000, boost::bind(&Listener::chatterCallback, this, _1, "User 2")));
        subs_.push_back(node_handle_.subscribe<std_msgs::String>("chatter", 1000, boost::bind(&Listener::chatterCallback, this, _1, "User 3")));
 }
```

I checked the code document, it seems that the line match this version of subscriber
http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/roscpp/html/node__handle_8h_source.html

It seems that the `push_back` code matches the bellowing version.

```
template<class M>
Subscriber subscribe(const std::string& topic, 
  uint32_t queue_size, 
  const boost::function<void (const boost::shared_ptr<M const>&)>& callback, 
  const VoidConstPtr& tracked_object = VoidConstPtr(), 
  const TransportHints& transport_hints = TransportHints())
{
  SubscribeOptions ops;
  ops.template init<M>(topic, queue_size, callback);
  ops.tracked_object = tracked_object;
  ops.transport_hints = transport_hints;
  return subscribe(ops);
}
```

I know the basic demos of publish and subscribe mechanism of ROS, but I am not so familiar with the advanced C++ templates.

Q1. `<std_msgs::String>`is the return type of `node_handle_.subscribe` is that right? Is this type match the first argument of the chatterCallback function?

Q2. Why we use `push_back()` to initialize these three callback functions? Are they running as separated thread after push into the `V_Subscriber`?

Q3. I also did not catch the meaning of **"On success, a Subscriber that, when all copies of it go out of scope, will unsubscribe from this topic.**". What is the scope and why it will go out of scope during the callback?

Does any could explain the logic here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234538/why-%22subs_.push_back%22-in-listener_with_userdata.cpp/) by [Weiwei](https://answers.ros.org/users/21100/weiwei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2016-05-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Answer for Q1:**

The return type of a function / method is *before* the function / method name. In this case it is `Subscriber`.

**Answer for Q2:**

The `subscribe` methods return a reference counted publisher. When all copies of it go out of scope it will unsubscribe from the topic. Therefore the subscribers are stored in a vector to prevent them from going out of scope. You could also store each subscriber in a local variable instead. I vector has nothing to do with threads.

**Answer for Q3:**

I think you need to google a bit about variable scope, reference counting and when such objects are being deleted. A simple example:

```
{
  Subscriber s = node_handle.subscribe<std_msgs::String>(...);
  // some more code
} <-- in this line the scope of variable "s" on the stack ends, therefore it is being removed
```

In case of an object it is being destructed. In case of a reference counted instance it is being destructed if no other reference is stored anywhere.

By storing the subscriber in the vector (which has a bigger scope) the subscriber is not being removed yet but stays around (in the case of the tutorial until the program terminates).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2016-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0